# Write a program to compute factorial of an integer in ARM assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm

Given an integer I have to write a function that returns its factorial value.

Here's my code for the factorial function:

```
bl getnum

move r3, r0

mov r1, #1   -- counter

mov r4, r0


loop:
   sub r0, r0, #1

   mul r3, r0, r3

   add r1, r1, #1  

   subs r1, r4  -- check if counter = the initial r0
beg loop

mov r0, r3

bl printnum
```

However, this code yields incorrect result. For example when I input 5 it gives 20 instead of 120. Can someone help me find where things go wrong? My logical reasoning seems to work but I don't know whether I made a syntax error that causes the program to run in a different way

Comment: When posting code you should copy-paste rather than typing it in, to avoid typos. I doubt that your actual code has a `beg` in it.

Answer (score 4):

`sub` writes back the result of the subtraction to the destination operand. That is not what you want here - you just want to do a comparision, so you should use `cmp`:

```
cmp r1, r4  -- cmp always updates the flags, so you don't need to write cmps
bne loop
```

However, your code doesn't handle the case where `n` is 0 or 1. Also, it's kind of unnecessary to use an additional counter (`r1`) when you already have a perfectly suitable counter in `r0`. So you could rewrite it into something like this:

```
mov r3, #1  -- default value
loop:
  cmp r0, #1
  -- if (n > 1) { r3 *= n; n--; goto loop; }
  mulgt r3, r0, r3
  subgt r0, r0, #1
  bgt loop
```

Comment: I was just about to post that same code. It's a great way to learn about all the conditional instructions to reduce code size.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic: It's somewhat less effective in thumb2 (where a conditional block like this needs an `IT` instruction, even if the assembler emits it automatically), and not available at all in AArch64.  For Thumb2, I think a [`cbz r0, after_loop`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFFHBB.html) before the loop would have the same total code size, but less inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this wonderful [post](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/02/07/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-10/).

As a side note, be aware that you aren't following the ARM calling [convention of ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_.28A32.29) to ensure proper context switching.

I think that you are using too many registers, try to reduce their number. Would be easier to track your code flow and debug.

Here is my final suggestion:

```
mov r3, #1
cmp r0, #0
beq end

factorial:
    mul r3, r3, r0
    sub r0, r0, #1 
    beg factorial 
end:              
    mov r0, r3
```

I think that in your solution you should change

```
subs r1, r4  -- check if counter = the initial r0
```

into

```
cmp r1, r4  -- check if counter = the initial r0
```

So you will check if `r1 > r4` without changing `r1`, otherwise you will exit after one loop.